# How to access the elements of array individually and fetch them

Tags: php, arrays

```
print_r($que);
```

output's this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => PHP allows you to send emails directly from a script [1] => How do you get information from a form that is submitted using the "get" method? [2] => In PHP you can use both single quotes ( ) and double quotes ( " " ) for strings: [3] => What does php stands for ? [4] => The PHP syntax is most similar to: [5] => What is the correct way to connect to a MySQL database? [6] => What is the correct way to include the file "time.inc" ? [7] => In PHP, the die() and exit() functions do the exact same thing. [8] => All variables in PHP start with which symbol? [9] => Include files must have the file extension ".inc" ) )
```

I need to print each element.

LIKE $que[0]; and $que[1]; and so on.

if i does `echo "$que[0]";` output comes out to be `Array` instead of `PHP allows you to send emails directly from a script`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$que[0]` is an array itself. To access the first element within the first element of `$que` you need to do `$que[0][0]`.

Comment: woh ! got it Thnx bro @xbonez